# Making a dataframe of bool values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[12,34,98,26],'b':[12,87,98,12],'c':[11,23,43,1]})


    a   b   c
0   12  12  11
1   34  87  23
2   98  98  43
3   26  12  1
```

I want to make a max_df which contains bool values. In df, if an entry in row is maximum of its row, there would be 'True' in place of that entry in max_df, otherwise there would be 'False'.
my max_df should look like,

```
      a       b       c
0   True    True    False
1   False   True    False
2   True    True    False
3   True    False   False
```

I wrote this code for this,

```
max_df = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
```

But it gives the value error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Your solution is working for me, which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I'm running on ubuntu, which has older version of python, on which it doesn't work. Unfortunately I can't upgrade the version as I don't have permissions for that. Is there any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is probably the best and it does work,

```
df.eq(df.max(axis=1),axis=0)
```

But as you said that you are using a ancient version in which it doesn't , then you can also try:

```
max_series = df.max(axis=1)
max_df  = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df:
    max_df[col] = df[col]==max_series
```

Which is a worst solution but I guess it will work in even older versions than yours.

If "df[col]==max_series" is not working for you then:

```
max_series = df.max(axis=1)
max_df = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df:
    max_df[col] = [df[col][i] == max_series[i] for i in range(len(df[col]))]
```

But at this point is just better to figure out how to get permissions to update your software, but most probably you won't need special permissions installing it in your user. If you are using a ubuntu machine it will be easy to do a new environment installing miniconda for instance or any other distribution/ package manager.

Comment: what will be my max_df in your code?

Comment: Your code is also giving the same error. :(

Comment: can you give your pd.__version__ ?

Comment: Python version is 3.8, I don't know the pd version.

Comment: print(pd.__version__)

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is the best. However, as you cannot upgrade `pandas`, you could also do something like this (one-liner):

```py
df_max = df.apply(lambda x: x==df.max(axis=1))
df_max

---------------------------
    a       b       c
0   True    True    False
1   False   True    False
2   True    True    False
3   True    False   False
---------------------------
```

Note, if this approach also throws an error, you could try this (as I would then suspect `df.max(axis=1)` to be the reason for your error):

```py
df_max = df.apply(lambda x: x==df.T.apply(lambda x: max(x)))
```

---

###### EDIT

You can try the following code instead:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[12,34,98,26],'b':[12,87,98,12],'c':[11,23,43,1]})

df["temp_max"] = df.T.apply(lambda x: max(x))
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.iloc[index, :-1] = [val == row[-1] for val in row[:-1]]
df.drop(columns=["temp_max"])
```

What you do here is to first assign the maximum of each row as a new column and then iterate over each row and compare it with the maximum of the row.

Comment: I guess using x==df.max(axis=1) is causing the problem. Your code is also giving the same error.

Comment: @User1917931829 does the second approach work?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. The problem is that we're trying to get the truth value of an array, which is ambiguous for my ubuntu python version.

Comment: I was thinking of applying applymap and getting the truthvalues by comparing each element with maximum of its rows using iterations over rows, but couldn't write a code for that.

Comment: @User1917931829 I assume you meant no? So the second approach is not working?

Comment: Yea, I meant no, it was a typo.

Comment: @User1917931829 I edited my answer, now you compare each value with the maximum of each row.